# Hibernate many to one - delete parent when no more childs

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade, many-to-one

i have a many to one relationship between two of my entities. now i want the parent to get removed when there are no more children.
my case:

class contactperson
class organisation

one organisation has a few contactpersons and every contactperson has one organisation. when all contactpersons of a organisation are removed, i want the organisation to get removed, too. is this possible by using cascade or something like that?

thanks, basti

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

1) in Organization.java

`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "organization", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ContactPerson> contactPerson= new ArrayList<ContactPerson>();`

and

2) in ContactPerson.java
 
`@ManyToOne
private Organization organization;`

Comment: This will only remove `ContactPerson` if `Organization` gets deleted, or if it's `ContactPerson` removed from List and not added to other organization (orphaned), but won't remove `Organization`.